# saving UIImage to file cost a lot of time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I'm trying to load pictures in iPhone Photos app, then save the selected pictures in to my app's folder, using ALAssetsLibrary, and have two issues:
1. the image file saved to disk is much bigger then original files in Photos app, for example, a picture is 2.8MB, but after saved to my app's folder, it's 6.4MB, following is the code:

```
        CGImageRef cgImage = [localPhoto thumbnail];

        NSString *path = @"/documents/test/1.jpeg";//the path is just an example
        BOOL succ;
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

        NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 1.0);
        succ = [data1 writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

2. the above code(saving 6.4MB image to file) costs about 1.6seconds, is it normal? is there anyway to make it faster?

Comment: I can't account for the time it takes, but the 1.0 image quality may be higher than the original image, and that may account for the size difference.  I know that when syncing screen optimized image versions are created for my iPhotos.  I wonder if there is a screen optimized version added to metadata or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with PNG representation of the image.

```
NSData *data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
```

or else reduce the image quality or JPG.

```
NSData *data1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5);
```

Comment: I did it, UIImagePNGRepresentation will generate a much bigger file, more than 10MB, I'll try to decrease the quality.

Comment: hoho, something interesting, when I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.5), the saved file is 1.4MB, this is just half of the original file(2.8MB) size, then I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.9), the saved file is 3.5MB,:), anyway, it's acceptable, I decided to use 0.9,  anyone has better suggestion?